# How to install Blender while retaining addons

Tags: add-on, installation

Since Blender is frequently updated, how do you install the latest version while keeping all of your addons including purchased addons from 3rd parties?

Comment: +1 Great question.

Answer (score 2):

New Blender versions can be installed along side the previous versions, meaning that your old install of Blender will continue to work with its add-ons.

For the new version of Blender you will have to install the add-ons again. If the add-on you've previously downloaded / purchased is compatible with the new version of Blender, you can use the same files (.zip, .py) for the installation of the add-on. Should they not be compatible, then you will have to check if an updated version of the add-on is available for that specific Blender version.

Add-ons for 2.79b and earlier can't be used in Blender 2.8x because of the changed API.

Comment: The reinstallation of add-ons for new releases is a bit cumbersome if you have many add-ons, especially ones that require configurations in the preferences. Migrating add-on installation would be a nice feature for future versions of Blender.

Comment: Are there any blender plans (or features to vote on) for migrating add-ons?

Comment: @melutovich this should be working now by selecting the "Load X.YZ Version" option in the splash screen when you start the newly installed version for the first time.